# MATLAB, how to change loop index inside for loops

Tags: matlab

I have a loop like this:

```
b = 1;
for c = 1 : 10;
  if b == 1
      c = 1 + 3
  end
end
```

What do I need to do to make to change `c`?
Because as I read through the help, MATLAB resets the loop counter `c` after it reaches `end`.

Is there any way to change the value of the loop counter from within a `for` loop?

Comment: Do you mean `c = c + 3`?  As written, it looks like you intend for the loop to never end, since `c` would always be set to `4`.

Comment: yes sir, what i mean is, that the loop in the for loops, will change its values to 4, and then growng, but in that code i think thats only make a 4, but still 10 times looping..

Comment: I would always avoid modifying loop indices within a loop - this can lead to some hard to find bugs. Either of the answers below are better ways of doing what you want.

Comment: You need to rewrite the question.  As written, you've written an endless loop.

Comment: @Pursuit et al - This is not an infinite loop. See [this blog post from Loren](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2006/07/19/how-for-works/#5).

Answer (score 10):

you could use a while loop instead of a for loop.

something like (I'm guessing you want to add 3 to c otherwise c = 4 could replace that line below)

```
b = 1;
c = 1;
while(c < 10)
    if b == 1
        c = c + 3
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Not really following what you're trying to do but are you looking to increase the value of c by 3 as opposed to 1 on each iteration of the loop?

You can do that with:

```
for i = 1:3:10
    // do something
end
```

this is the equivalent of the more common for loop syntax:

```
for (c = 1; c <= 10; c+=3)
{
    // do something
}
```